# Ux/ui design for different countries in the world

Tags: ux-designer, country

Cultures in the world have a different feel for ux/ui design, for example, europa look design as cold colors, latinAmerica look design as hot colors.

Should one design for different countries?

Comment: Hi Cristian. Your question is very difficult to make out. Please consider editing it and expanding on what you are trying to achieve, or elaborate more on what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: Answer yes: its called "localisation". There are quite a lot of previous questions on here about it.

Comment: I've editted the English a bit which hopefully makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You should design for different countries. This is known as Localization.

UX Design is *not* different for different cultures of the world. "UX" is a process, not one thing that happens and then ends. UX is about focusing the design process around the user. The way that is done may be different from company to company, or country to country, but the purpose and end goal is still the same.

UI Design *is* different for different cultures. Here are just some items that are different depending on the audience you are designing for:

**Language and reading direction**

In Europe and the US text tends to run left-to-right.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv8N6E.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Japanese can run left-to-right, or top-to-bottom and right-to-left

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwrjRR.png)</sup>

In Arabic and Hebrew the character display can run *both* left-to-right and right-to-left. Additionally, in Arabic the characters change shape when combined with others.

**Layout**

Due to the above, and other cultural issues, the layout of a page is not necessarily the same. A simple example is taking the *left* hand navigation bar and moving it to the *right* when translating the page to Arabic.

**Spelling**

- color vs colour
- Program vs Programme
- Center vs Centre
- Internationalization vs Internationalisation

**Punctuation**

- Question marks:

  - French, English: ?
  - Spanish: ¿ ?
  - Greek: ;
- Periods:

  - English: .
  - Hindi: |

**Names**

Cristian Ramón vs Ramón Cristian

**Symbol meaning**

- [Different numbers have different significance](http://www.dailyinfographic.com/lucky-unlucky-numbers-around-the-world-infographic) between countries.

[image]

- [Different hand gestures have different meaning](https://blog.busuu.com/what-hand-gestures-mean-in-different-countries/) between countries.

[image]

- Different symbols also have different meaning. The check mark has no meaning in China; where an 'O' means correct.

**Color**

Color does not represent the same meaning in different countries. There are lots of great articles around the web on this one, because it is so visual. Here is one: [Color Meanings From Around the World](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/communication/colors-and-what-they-mean-around-the-world.html), which includes this nice graphic:

[image]

**Units of measure**

Imperial vs. metric.

**Currency**

Not only does the symbol change, but the position (before or after the amount) changes. Also, the same symbol can be used by different countries to represent their local currency.

$ does not always mean US currency.

**Dates and time**

01/02/2016 = Jan. 2nd 2016, or Feb. 1st 2016

## Design for the audience

If your website (or other product) is going to be consumed by different cultures around the world, you need to design for them individually. Here, for example, are pictures of Coca-cola's website (an old version) from different countries:

**U.S.**

[image]

**India**

[image]

**China**

[image]

**Same product. Different audience. Different UI design. Good UX.**

Comment: Well that's pretty comprehensive :-)

Comment: There's a hand gesture for "your wife is cheating on you"? You think simply telling the guy would suffice..

Comment: Cultural colour tables like the ones shown here should always be taken with a grain of salt. Yes, it's nice and fun to sort basic attributes into colour tables, but overall, nowadays also in far Eastern cultures, red and green are traffic lights colours meaning *stop* and *go*, respectively; in central Europe, yellow will probably make most people think of the post service or taxis before coming up with "happiness, joy, and caution", and choosing a colour scheme that is *different* from those of competitors may well overrule any implied meaning of colours, to name just three issues.

Answer (score 0):

The standardization versus localization in web design will be always a subject for debate.

I think for this topic will be always different opinions, but I think the most important element is how different is the UI in a country from the international websites with a recognizable design and establish what users expect.

The trends like minimalism, the need for simplicity, the desire to have a multi-language international website, make the standardization a more natural choice.

Global patterns and rules tend to be confirmed and safe to use. To design in a more particular way include knowing the set of sensitive elements and strategies that should be applied.